# fresh install of npm generates "ELOOP: too many symbolic links" error

Tags: node.js, npm

I have googled for the answer to this but the "solutions" seem to be missing something in my case.  I just tried to update yarn.js to version 2 on Windows 10.  Part of the upgrade process wants me to upgrade npm global modules first.  running:

```
npm update -g
```

as admin or myself gives me:

```
$ npm update -g
npm ERR! code ELOOP
npm ERR! syscall stat
npm ERR! path \\fs2.my.company.com\Home\
npm ERR! errno -62
npm ERR! ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, stat '\\fs2.my.company.com\Home\'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     \\fs2.my.company.com\Home\MyAccount\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-09T17_30_03_007Z-debug.log
```

The referenced log file contains:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'update',
1 verbose cli   '-g'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.15.1
4 verbose npm-session a666bee41aec0454
5 verbose update computing outdated modules to update
6 verbose stack Error: ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, stat '\\fs2.my.company.com\Home\'
6 verbose stack     at eloop (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:58:17)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:19:11)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
7 verbose cwd C:\Users\MyAccount
8 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
9 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "update" "-g"
10 verbose node v14.15.1
11 verbose npm  v6.14.8
12 error code ELOOP
13 error syscall stat
14 error path \\fs2.my.company.com\Home\
15 error errno -62
16 error ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, stat '\\fs2.my.company.com\Home\'
17 verbose exit [ -62, true ]
```

The other reports of this I have seen suggest that there is a corrupt file in a `node_modules` folder.  I have uninstalled yarn, and node (plus npm) and have hunted for and removed App_Data folders related to them.  I have reinstalled nodejs at this point so everything *should* be pure.

What am I missing?

Comment: I answered the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65796869/global-install-of-npm-generates-eloop-too-many-symbolic-links-error-network/68189764#68189764)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the issue was that the `npm` related cache and associated files were pointing to a location that is a mounted file system on Windows 10.  I have discovered that one can create a `.npmrc` file and specify/override default values for a lot of config items.  I set the `prefix` and `cache` paths in there to point to folders on my local machine.

I am having other issues now but this one seems closed.

Cheers