# global install of npm generates “ELOOP: too many symbolic links” error (network user)

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10

Environment: Windows 10, network user, npm@6.14.8, node@12.20.0

Steps to recreate: Either install any npm package globally or update npm globally.

This problem is very similar, in fact the same as this [SOF question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65222253/12554872).

Here is the error message in the terminal. I am copy-pasting the other question's error message and logs. The values are the exact same. Both of us were network users:

```sh
$ npm update -g
npm ERR! code ELOOP
npm ERR! syscall stat
npm ERR! path \\fs2.my.company.com\Home\
npm ERR! errno -62
npm ERR! ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, stat '\\fs2.my.company.com\Home\'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     \\fs2.my.company.com\Home\MyAccount\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-09T17_30_03_007Z-debug.log
```

And here is the referenced log file:

```sh
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'update',
1 verbose cli   '-g'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.15.1
4 verbose npm-session a666bee41aec0454
5 verbose update computing outdated modules to update
6 verbose stack Error: ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, stat '\\fs2.my.company.com\Home\'
6 verbose stack     at eloop (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:58:17)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:19:11)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
6 verbose stack     at realpathCached (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\realpath.js:39:10)
7 verbose cwd C:\Users\MyAccount
8 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
9 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "update" "-g"
10 verbose node v14.15.1
11 verbose npm  v6.14.8
12 error code ELOOP
13 error syscall stat
14 error path \\fs2.my.company.com\Home\
15 error errno -62
16 error ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, stat '\\fs2.my.company.com\Home\'
17 verbose exit [ -62, true ]
```

My guess is that the problem occurs due to me being a network ActiveDirectory user. The solution was to overwrite the cache and prefix of npm in npmrc. I found out my npmrc file is located in "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc".

So I am writing in this npmrc file the new cache and prefix values:

```js
prefix=C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
cache=C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-cache
```

There was no "npm-cache" folder in that location. I think the cache location is wrong here. I got this from: [this SOF answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14841880/12554872). I am also trying `cache=\\company.com\users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`.

I am getting a new permission error:

```sh
$ npm install node-windows -g
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\.staging
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\.staging'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\.staging'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\.staging'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\.staging'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\.staging',
npm ERR!   parent: 'node-windows'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

So, OS is not allowing me to create the ".staging" folder in `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules`.

I am sure I have the wrong values for cache and prefix paths. I think the npmrc location is the right one.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same issue. Finally what worked for me is changing the cache and prefix location to my local AppData Folder. In order to do so I did the following steps

1. Copy the npm-cashe folder from Active directory AppData folder to my local AppData folder (C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming)
2. Create an Empty folder and rename it npm
3. Edit the nprc file with the notepad(use it with Admin privillages)
   C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm

   ```
   prefix=C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm \
   cache=C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
   ```
4. Change the global values of the cache and prefix using the following commands [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836053/how-can-i-change-the-cache-path-for-npm-or-completely-disable-the-cache-on-win)

   ```
   > npm config set cache C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache --global
   > npm config set prefix C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm --global
   ```

Those steps worked for me